# Update a slow-loading variable in Tornado without blocking REST responsiveness

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, tornado, data-sharing

I'm trying to run Tornado REST that returns data from a very large DataFrame.

Because the data changes frequently, ***I'd like to update the DataFrame frequently in the backgroundwithout blocking the REST responsiveness.***

This code blocks every time update_df is called, and REST requests time out (or simply wait 60 seconds - the time of the DF update.)

I have tried running df_update as a `multiprocessing` and making a Singleton to store the DF (that main uses) and both instantiating the singleton object in the thread AND passing the actual singleton object into the update_df thread - but the df within the Tornado classes (I.e. DFHandler) never gets re-updated with the new data.

I have tried `multiprocessing` solutions from these  posts. Some worked to update the df variable, but ***always blocked*** the tornado responsiveness. Others simply didn't work with errors or failed to update the variable.

- [Make Singleton class in Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077043/make-singleton-class-in-multiprocessing)
- [Share list between process in python server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455462/share-list-between-process-in-python-server/25456494#25456494)
- [Shared variable in python's multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377426/shared-variable-in-pythons-multiprocessing)
- [Python multiprocessing without blocking parent process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920110/python-multiprocessing-without-blocking-parent-process)
- [How do I stop Tornado web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375220/how-do-i-stop-tornado-web-server)

I've tried running the **Tornado** server in a multiprocessing thread, and a while loop in main loading the updated DF and then ending and restarting the Tornado thread after the DF is updated - but every attempt at that ended with a socket open error when the tornado server thread was started again.

- [how to to terminate process using python's multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053618/how-to-to-terminate-process-using-pythons-multiprocessing)
- [How do I close all sockets opened by Tornado?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179302/how-do-i-close-all-sockets-opened-by-tornado)

I've tried asyncio, but it fails because tornado itself is using asyncio events, so it fails with the error `"asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop"`

- [Non-blocking I/O with asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676954/non-blocking-i-o-with-asyncio)
- ["AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'coroutine'." in Python 3.11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74345065/attributeerror-module-asyncio-has-no-attribute-coroutine-in-python-3-11)

Any suggestions?

```
import json
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver

df = <preload_inital_df> #very slow (60 seconds)

def update_df():
    df = <RE_load_changed_df> #very slow (60 seconds)

class RootPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello World")

class DFHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def initialize(self, df):
        self.df = df
    def get(self):
        self.write(df.to_json())

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            ('/',             RootPageHandler, {}),
            ('/df',           DFHandler,       {'df': df}),
            ]

        settings = dict(template_path='/templates',
                        static_path='/static', 
                        debug=True)

        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

# Run the instance
application = Application()
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8888)

# Callback function to update configs
some_time_period = 600000 # Once every 100 second
tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(update_df, some_time_period).start()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: The code above you showed,not use 'asyncio', it will block.Try to use 'asyncio'. Then,try to use the function 'run_in_executor'  to use thread or process .Also,if it is a big data DataFrame,will the 'to_json'  take a long time?it is a block function.

Comment: Hi @lanhao945. I did try using asyncio, but it fails because Tornado itself uses asyncio and causes it to raise an `asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop` error

Comment: Show mini codes about  the way you use asyncio. asyncio has apis,which no need to   start or run again in a running event loop.May you tried a wrong api.